How to solve exception in fazecast/jSerialComm/SerialPort when ran from command line
I'm using Netbeans IDE 21.  The application works fine when ran from the IDE.  I'm ready to deploy and tried to run it from the jar file(s) and it throws the same exception every time.  The OS is Linux Mint 21.3.  Java is version is JDK 19.  Yes, I have modified the pom.xml to fix other errors and I suspect this is where the issue is but I'm at my wits end.  I now exactly where the exception is being thrown, it's when I instantiate a serial port object.  I examined the .jar file with archive manager and it looks like the library is not getting packaged with the build.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.
david@david-OptiPlex-9010:~/Documents/Netbeans/ParticleCountAlarm/target$ java -jar ParticleCountAlarm-1.0.jar |more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fazecast/jSerialComm/SerialPort
    at alk.okc.particlecountalarm.mySerialPort.connect(mySerialPort.java:20)
    at alk.okc.particlecountalarm.mySerialPort.<init>(mySerialPort.java:15)
    at alk.okc.particlecountalarm.MainFrame.startSerialTimer(MainFrame.java:82)
    at alk.okc.particlecountalarm.MainFrame.<init>(MainFrame.java:17)
    at alk.okc.particlecountalarm.ParticleCountAlarm.main(ParticleCountAlarm.java:6)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPort
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 5 more





<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ALK.OKC</groupId>
    <artifactId>ParticleCountAlarm</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fazecast</groupId>
            <artifactId>jSerialComm</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.4</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>19</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>19</maven.compiler.target>
        <exec.mainClass>alk.okc.particlecountalarm.ParticleCountAlarm</exec.mainClass>
    </properties>  
    <build>      
        <plugins>
            <!-- Maven JAR Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>alk.okc.particlecountalarm.ParticleCountAlarm</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Maven Source Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version> <!-- Use the latest version here -->
            </plugin>
            <!-- Maven Javadoc Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.3</version> <!-- Use the latest version here -->
            </plugin>
            <!-- Maven Deploy Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version> <!-- Use the latest version here -->
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>  
</project>



I switched from Maven to Ant and was able to solve it in 5 minutes after spending hours unsuccessfully with Maven trying to package a single library.  Not a big fan of Maven.
